# Is there a way to specify how long I want an access token to be valid for?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, authentication, oauth2

I am following the explicit authentication path. I am not passing `no_expiry` as part of the scope.

After the final `POST` step, I receive back an `expires` value of `86399` (*just* shy of a full day).

It seems that my options are to either take this nearly full day or never expire the tokens. Is there a middle ground? I don't want to annoy my users by requiring them to re-authenticate daily but I'm also hesitant to request non-expiring tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I always get 86399 too. And, no, you can't specify an interval other than `no_expiry`.

But you ***can*** call [`/access-tokens/{accessTokens}/invalidate`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/invalidate-access-tokens) at whatever interval you wish.

So, for less user annoyance, set `no_expiry` but then call `/invalidate` every, say, 8 days, for example.